# Cosmos DB expensive query when comparing two properties

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem with cosmos sql query, it's simple but also expensive:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.key = '<key>' and c.lastAction > c.lastSync
```

With around 60k records in this key it's using crazy 1600 RUs while returning 0 records. I tried using composite indexes but they didn't help. What's strange when I do c.lastAction < c.lastSync it's returning a big 1000 records page with just of around 100 RUs.

The lastAction and lastSync are just a date types, ex: '2021-12-07T08:20:00.877192Z', '2021-12-07T07:40:35Z'
(I know this model should be designed differently but this is where we are at the moment)
I'm also thinking about adding property computed during upsert that will return result of c.lastAction > c.lastSync if nothing else will work.

Edit
It looks like it's doing a full read of records to read this c.lastSync, if so is there a way to index/workaround it?

Comment: `Range queries with DateTime strings as filters are only supported if the DateTime strings are all in UTC and the same length` - do you have same length?

Comment: well, they are not, I'll check if format change fixes the problem, thanks

Comment: Well, I made a test and it didn't change anything, I tried various different combinations with 10k records, and even when dates are exactly the same as string in db the cost is the same
The idea with flag works perfectly but I'll need to make a data migration :/
what's interesting such query:
SELECT * FROM c
where c.key = '<key>' 
and (c.isSynced = true or (c.lastAction > c.lastSync))
is even worse than just dates